# JRE and Structure (population genetics software)

Tags: java, ubuntu, structure, genetics

Since the software Structure takes quite a while to run, more than 24 hours in many cases, I was thinking in having two computers running different datasets.

I wanted to install the software in my personal computer (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, 64-bit). After downloading and decompressing I tried to install it. At this step the program asks me where the JRE is located as it can not identify java automatically. I have followed the instructions here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-jre#1-overview . Whatever path I gave it, it keep saying it is not a compatible JRE. At this stage I have no clue what the software is asking for, any help will be more than welcomed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, already solved the issue. I had several versions of Java at the end and the right path was /usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_291/bin/java